# Error 0x80045561 in VoiceCommandDefinition Initializing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, voice-recognition

I am getting the following error on the line on code that says,

```
await VoiceCommandService.InstallCommandSetsFromFileAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///VoiceCommandDefinition1.xml"));
```

Error is

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80045561

The Error only occurs on Windows Phone 8. When I try on Emulator running on Windows Phone 8.1, its all fine.

***I checked on MSDN and it says that this error code means that The CommandSet element contains content other than Command or PhraseList elements.***
**

> Note: My VCD file contains PhraseTopics and not PhraseLists. Is it something related to
>   that?

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of PhraseTopics was only introduced in Windows Phone 8.1. If you want to use Voice Commands in Windows Phone 8.0 you'll need to have a seperate VCD file using PhraseLists.

Comment: Yes, I learnt that after reading various forums. What are my options if I want to have names of cities from around the works in phrase lists? I cannot define all of them.

Comment: I agree it'd be difficult to put that many cities in a VCD. You may just need to restrict this feature to 8.1